# How to deploy Spring boot application with GitLab serverless?

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, serverless

I configured a Google could demo project and created a cluster for it in the GitLab Serverless settings for a Hello world Spring boot application. The only information I find on deploying applications is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/serverless/#deploying-serverless-applications which might explain how to deploy a Ruby application only. I'm not sure about that because none of the variables used in the script are explained and the hint

> Note: You can reference the sample Knative Ruby App to get started.

is somehow confusing because if I'm not familiar with building Ruby applications which I'm not, that won't get me started.

Following the instruction to put

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: gcr.io/triggermesh/tm@sha256:e3ee74db94d215bd297738d93577481f3e4db38013326c90d57f873df7ab41d5
  only:
    - master
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    - tm -n "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" --config "$KUBECONFIG" deploy service "$CI_PROJECT_NAME" --from-image "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" --wait
```

in `.gitlab-ci.yml` causes the `deploy` stage to fail due to

```
$ tm -n "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" --config "$KUBECONFIG" deploy service "$CI_PROJECT_NAME" --from-image "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" --wait
2019/02/09 11:08:09 stat /root/.kube/config: no such file or directory, falling back to in-cluster configuration
2019/02/09 11:08:09 Can't read config file
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My `Dockerfile` which allows to build locally looks as follows:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11
COPY . .
RUN mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar target/hello-world-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

(the version in the filename doesn't make sense for further deployment, but that's a follow-up problem).

Answer (score 1):

Reason is a mismatch in the `environment` value specified in `.gitlab-ci.yml` and the GitLab Kubernetes configuration, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#troubleshooting-missing-kubeconfig-or-kube_token for details.